# Big d3.js graph, canvas or server-side rendering?

Tags: python, canvas, svg, d3.js

I'm using d3.js to visualize timeseries-data sent from my python backend (via Websocket).
The usual amount of data for one graph is about 120 entries (2 hours of data, 1 entry per Minute). This is running fine, gets updated every minute.

But it should also be capable of visualizing data from a month or more (could be up to a year), also in a 1-Minute-interval.
Rendering such an amount of data is too much for SVG.

I'm thinking of the following alternatives:

- Rendering it in a canvas. Is it really that much faster?
- Switching to another library like Highchart.js (Saw a demo with ~50k entries)
- Rendering the SVG/JPG/PNG on the server. Any experience on rendering d3.js server-side with e.g. phantom.js? I'd like to reuse the already written graph-models. But it could also be any other library which is able to render the data (generate the graphs with python)

What would you recommend?

Comment: I'd argue to go with the super-cool [rendering SVG files on the client](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-arent-you-using-svg/) approach.

Comment: @Droogans Yes, im already doing this for the small graphs. But my problems are the big graphs (with huge amount of data)..

Comment: Hmmm...d3 should be running fine with 120 datapoints.  What issues are you having with the d3 solution?  Canvas is great at presenting charts that change from second-to-second--yes, it's that much fast.  But it is not strong on interactivity (like drill-downs or pop-up informational notes).  If you have static charts to present (charts that have been saved to image) canvas can start by presenting a static image inside canvas and then updating the canvas as needed with updated datapoints (the reusability you mentioned).

Comment: @markE As I mentioned, 120 datapoints are no problem, but it slows down massively as the dataset grows. I'd prefer canvas so I can save the graphs and don't have to convert SVG <-> Image on the server. But my question is, if I have to render thousands of datapoints, would the canvas be capable of it or are there other techniques?

Comment: Sounds like you have two use cases for your viewer.  I would create another chart that views historical data.  You could populate the chart with repeated ajax calls depending on the zoom level vs desired performance.  You may find loading a years worth of data points in the background is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Note that d3 supports using javascript's [buffered arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays). SVG plots with thousands of time series data points has worked fine in my experience (even with multiple sources of live data streaming at 20ms updates via websockets).

For example if you pack all your data in Python; you might not need to do this in your live view as your update rate is relatively slow:

```
import struct
# fake data point
p = [56435367, 200, 1]
# <=little endian, d=float64 (for time), d=float64
msg_str = struct.pack('<' + 'd' * len(p), *p)
print(msg_str)
b'\x00\x00\x008\x15\xe9\x8aA\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00i@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?'
```

Then via your websocket that gets to javascript, where you can do something like:

```
this.ws.onmessage = function(e){
    // Just pump the raw bytes straight into CircularBuffer
    graph.databuffer.push(e.data);
    ...
```

And when you want to plot, assuming g is your reference to the D3 svg:

```
// Get a Float64Array containing all the values
var series_data = graph.databuffer.get_array_stream();
g.attr("d", graph.line(d3.zip(time, series_data)));
```

Naturally this should be even easier if you have all the data upfront. Are you perhaps plotting points instead of a single path? I found browsers struggle with plotting tens of thousands of individual circles (especially if they all move every 20ms!) but they can handle a path very easily.

Comment: upvoted! I have a similar case and am trying to make a real time candlestick chart, i read a post from Microsoft https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/gg193983(v=vs.85) which states real time charts should be done in Canvas, in my case i would need to update the candles 50 times a second over websocket, and would have less than 1000 candles in most cases, do you think canvas makes sense for the same or would you go SVG, Did you face any problems translating the SVG charts infinitely for shifting the graph while rendering live data?

Comment: I didn't have any trouble with SVG but this was 5 years ago and I'm no longer up to speed with this stuff! For what it is worth I'd take the old/expired data off the DOM (filter in js) if you're planning on leaving this up for a long time. From memory I used a circular buffer to solve that exact problem. Good luck!